# reRender problem In Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce, user-interface

I have one checkbox in an object I want to update that checkbox in visualforce page, I'm able to update that checkbox successfully using(command button) apex controller, but that problem here is I want to display the output of that checkbox field without refreshing a page, I'm trying using a `reRender` attribute to that command button called Update but's not displaying the checkbox output.

[image]

Visualforce page coding:

```
 <apex:outputpanel id="counter" style="overflow:scroll;" layout="block">         
          <apex:actionStatus id="counterStatus" startText=" (Fetching...)" stopText=" (done)"/>

              <apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail" Id="Refre">
              <apex:panelGroup id="ref2" >
               <apex:outputPanel id="ref1" styleClass="tableContainer" layout="block" style="height:420px" rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(quo))}"> 

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!quo}" var="q" rendered="{!(quo.size!= 0) && (quo.size < 999)}"  id="tb2Quotes" styleclass="floatingHeaderTable" style="overflow:scroll;height:250px;width:100%"> 

                 **<apex:column value="{!q.Quote_Line_Item__r.Order_Received__c}" styleClass="noWrap" style="border:1px solid #D7D8D9" headerValue="Order Received"/>**
                 <apex:column value="{!q.Discount__c}" styleClass="noWrap" style="border:1px solid #D7D8D9" headerValue="Discount"/>
                 <apex:column styleClass="noWrap" style="border:1px solid #D7D8D9;height:5px;" headerValue="Quote Preview">
                 <apex:commandbutton value="Quote Preview"  onclick="return window.open('/apex/QuotePreview?id={!q.Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__c}')" style="font-size: 5pt; color: black"  />
                 </apex:column>
                 <apex:column styleClass="noWrap" style="border:1px solid #D7D8D9" headerValue="Open Quote">
                 <apex:commandbutton value="open Quote" onclick="return window.open('https://nicomatic.my.salesforce.com/{!q.Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__c}')" style="font-size: 5pt; color: black" />
                 </apex:column> 
                 *<apex:column styleClass="noWrap" style="border:1px solid #D7D8D9"  >
                 <apex:facet name="header">Priority <apex:COMMandLink style="color: green" action="{!allupdateOrderReceived}" value="header" rerender="Refre" Value="!ALL Order Receved Update" /> </apex:facet>  
                        <apex:commandButton value="Update" action="{!updateOrderReceived}"  reRender="Refre,counter">
                          <apex:param name="selected" value="{!q.Quote_Line_Item__r.Id}" assignTo="{!selected}" /> 

                       </apex:commandButton>*
              <!--   
              <apex:facet name="header">Priority <apex:commandLink style="color: green" action="{!updateOrderReceived}" value="header" Value="!Order Received Update" > 
                                 <apex:param name="Selected" 
                                    value="{!q.Quote_Line_Item__r.Id}" 
                                   /> </apex:commandLink></apex:facet>   
               <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!q.Quote_Line_Item__r.Order_Received__c}" /> -->
              <!--   <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!q.Quote_Line_Item__r.Order_Received__c}" />
                 <apex:commandbutton value="Update"  style="font-size: 5pt; color: black" /> -->
                 </apex:column>           
            </apex:pageBlockTable>          
             <apex:outputText rendered="{!(quo.size = 0)}" value="There are no records to display." />
              <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(quo))}">
                 <apex:outputText rendered="{!quo.size > 999 }" value="Refine search Records should be less than 1000"  />
             </apex:outputPanel>  
              </apex:outputPanel>
              </apex:panelGroup>   

        </apex:pageBlock> 

           </apex:outputpanel>
```

Comment: rerender `ref1`.

Comment: @PragatiJain It's not working

Comment: What about `{!$Component.ref1}`?

Comment: @PragatiJain No it's not I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've completed this challenge with the help controller by adding an extra method for reRender and getting display the values.